# Sub string from character string using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm scraping PDF reports for their data.
I'm trying to extract the location the report is based off. I've got a character string with the location, and then a rolling 13 months header seen here:

```
header_line <- "Corp                                        Dec '20 Jan '21 Feb '21 Mar '21 Apr '21 May '21 Jun '21 Jul '21 Aug '21 Sep '21 Oct '21 Nov '21 Dec '21"
```

I'd like to extract all characters from the beginning of the string to the start of WHATEVER month could be appearing after Because it's a rolling 13-month report, it could be any of those months abbreviations next to the location.

I have this working for the above example, but I'm not sure how to create an "Or pattern" with regex. I know I could brute force it with a loop or apply function, but I was hoping there was a less dirty way.

```
stringr::str_extract(header_line, "[^Dec]+")
[1] "Corp                                        "
```

Comment: How about this? `strsplit(header_line, paste(month.abb, collapse="|"))[[1]][1]`

Comment: What does a _"a rolling 13 months header"_ have to do with a regex you're looking for ? Begin of string to a date = `^.*?(?=a rolling 13 months header)`

Comment: `str_extract(header_line, sprintf('.*?(?=%s)', paste(month.abb, collapse = '|')))`

Comment: Match the first month and year and everything after it replacing that with an empty string. `rx <- sprintf("(%s) '\\d\\d.*", paste(month.abb, collapse = "|"));
sub(rx, "", header_line)`   No packages needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to anticipate the possible cases that the location could be, but the below solution may cover most of it. It will match everything prior to 3 alphabetical characters, followed by a space, and apostrophe, and 2 digits.

```
str_extract(header_line, '^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\'\\d{2})')
```

Test cases:

```
header_line <- "Corp                                       Dec '20 Jan '21 Feb '21 Mar '21 Apr '21 May '21 Jun '21 Jul '21 Aug '21 Sep '21 Oct '21 Nov '21 Dec '21"
header_line2 <- "Corp multiple words                                       Dec '20 Jan '21 Feb '21 Mar '21 Apr '21 May '21 Jun '21 Jul '21 Aug '21 Sep '21 Oct '21 Nov '21 Dec '21"
header_line3 <- "Corp multiple words 1                                       Dec '20 Jan '21 Feb '21 Mar '21 Apr '21 May '21 Jun '21 Jul '21 Aug '21 Sep '21 Oct '21 Nov '21 Dec '21"
header_line4 <- "Corp multiple 444                                       Dec '20 Jan '21 Feb '21 Mar '21 Apr '21 May '21 Jun '21 Jul '21 Aug '21 Sep '21 Oct '21 Nov '21 Dec '21"

str_extract(header_line, '^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\'\\d{2})')
[1] "Corp"   

str_extract(header_line2, '^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\'\\d{2})')
[1] "Corp multiple words"  

str_extract(header_line3, '^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\'\\d{2})')
[1] "Corp multiple words 1"  

str_extract(header_line4, '^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\'\\d{2})')
[1] "Corp multiple 444"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely helpful. I have some locations like, "(MI) Traverse RMC - Traverse City, MI"
So I'm afraid it would get stuck at the RMC part of the string. Oh! Nevermind! I read your explanation wrong! Yes this should work! Thanks~

Comment: Yes, that location should be correctly extracted with this.